# Will moving a magnet through cupped hands change the nerve signals through the hand?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Basically nerve signals are electric impulses travelling from the brain to body parts. What would happen if we move a magnet through cupped hands. Would it somehow interfere with the current of the nerve impulses?

Comment: It depends on how fast you could move the magnet. If you could do it fast enough, you would feel a noticeable tingle and there would be serious health effects at even higher speeds. The only place I ever felt an induced voltage from a switched magnetic field was in an MRI machine (the gradient coils produce a sensation), but there seem to be magnetic neural stimulators that are much stronger than that, still.

Comment: Check out "transcranial magnetic stimulation."

Answer (score 2):

Basically, nothing would happen. Your nerves aren't unbroken wires, nor are they coiled for maximum effect like in a generator. Nerves only transmit signals electrically within the neuron, between neurons you have a largely chemical process. Even with incredibly powerful magnets, such as in a MRI tube, or a particle accelerator, the induction would still be negligible, and we know this because these environments aren't instantly fatal, or even incredibly damaging. Errant electrical pulses in the body are very dangerous, especially to the heart and the brain, and it only takes a tiny charge before it's lights out.